# How to make only one Button selected when clicked -QUIZ ANDROID

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-button

I am trying to implement a quiz whereby the user selects one from four buttons. When they click on the button it becomes selected, but then what I want to do is make any other button that was selected before to be reset to normal. This is my class and code, but it doesn't disable the other buttons:

```
public class QuizOne extends Fragment{
        Button one;
        Button two;
        Button three;
        Button four;
        boolean selected = false;

        public QuizOne(){

        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.quiz, container, false);
            one = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ones);
            two = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.twos);
            three = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.threes);
            four = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fours);
            selectedButton();
            return rootView;
        }

        public void selectedButton(){
            one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(selected){
                        one.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    }
                    else {
                        one.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                        selected = true;
                    }
                }
            });
            two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(selected){
                        two.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    }
                    else {
                        two.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                        selected = true;
                    }
                }
            });
            three.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(selected){
                        three.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    }
                    else {
                        three.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                        selected = true;
                    }
                }
            });
            four.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(selected){
                        four.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    }
                    else {
                        four.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                        selected = true;
                    }
                }
            });
        }

}
```

So its the `selectedButton()` method that I am struggling on. Because say if a user clicks on a button and then changes their mind after and selects another button then the previous button should be disabled. Also after clicking the button I want to go to the next tab

Comment: in else of every button you have to set color for every button

Comment: Why not use a single listener for each button. When a button is pressed, keep a reference to that button. So in further clicks, check if that ref is not null and set its state accordingly. See that View in the onClick method, is the button that is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to rethink your whole design. There's easier ways with way less code. Try something like this :

```
public class QuizOne extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    ....
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.quiz, container, false);
        one = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ones);
        one.setOnClickListener(this);

    // and so on ...


   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {

       setButtonsGray();
       v.setBackgroundColor(COLOR.Yellow);

   }

   private void setButtonsGray(){
       one.setBackgroundColor(COLOR.Gray);
       two.setBackgroundColor(COLOR.Gray);
       // and so on ...
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm! Thing is how do I go to the next tab when the button is clicked?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with next Tab. Put the code which takes you to the next Tab in the onClick(View v) method.

Comment: Never mind, I got it working. As you were the first to give a proper solution I have up-voted and accepted your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If i clearly understand your problem , one way to do this if you want to follow your first write logic is when you click your `button` to set yellow color to it and gray color to evryone exept clicket `button`

```
public void selectedButton() {
        one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    one.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    two.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                    three.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                    four.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);


            }
        });
        two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    two.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    one.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                    three.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                    four.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

            }
        });
        three.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    three.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    one.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                    two.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                    four.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

                }

        });
        four.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    four.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    one.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                    two.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                    three.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

            }
        });
    }
```

but there are many ways to achive this for sure..